# Best regex to match an opening then closing HTML tags, no matter what content

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-2.2

I'm parsing an HTML source as a string, and I want to remove all `<style>` tags. Here's my regex:

```
/<style.*?>[\s\S]*?<\/style>/i
```

NB: The question mark after the star makes it [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

If you run this code on the following HTML extract (rather small, around 1,000 chars), it takes over 25s to run. On the full HTML page, it still won't complete after 20 minutes.

```
text = "<main><h4>Une expérience reconnue</h4> <p class=\"home\">Entrez dans la communauté Initiative et <b>rejoignez nos 400 clients</b> qui font croitre chaque jour leur business.<br/><br/> <style=\"text-align: right;\"><a href=\"/references/\"><button class=\"btn btn-border btn-round waves-effect lighten-1 demo2 \" data-color=\"#e9763e\">EN SAVOIR+</button></a></p> </div></li> </ul> </div> <div class=\"col m8 offset-m1 s12\"> <!-- Partie mockup --> <ul class=\"mockup\"><!-- 0 --> <li><img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/pilotage-crm.png\" /></li> <!--style=\"width:3000px;height:1800px;\"--> <li><img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/CRM-simple.png\"/></li> <!-- 2 --> <li><img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/prix-CRM.png\"/></li> <!-- 3 --> <li><img src=\"wp-content/themes/abonline/img/slider-mockup/iPadConfig.png\"/></li> <!-- 4 --> <li><img src=\"wp-content/uploads/2017/04/clients-CRM.png\"/></li> </ul> </div> </div> </div> <section id=\"slider-iconPlus\"> <div class=\"container\"> <div class=\"iconPlus row\"> <div class=\"iconData col l3 m6 s6\"> <img id=\"hovData\" class=\"data\" src=\"wp-content/themes/abonline/img/slider-mockup/DataSecure.png\" alt=\"png\" /><br/>"
text.gsub!(/<style.*?>[\s\S]*?<\/style>/i, '')
```

The problem comes from the fact that, in the input, there are some `<style>` tags without the closing `</style>`. With the `[\s\S]*?` part, my understanding is that the regex has to parse the full string to match a closing `</style>` but doesn't find any. Unfortunately I have no control on the input, so I must fix the regex.

I could replace `[\s\S]*?` with `[^<]*` to match anything until the beginning of the closing `</style>` but that seems wrong, what if there's a `<` char within the style definition?

```
text.gsub!(/<style.*?>[^<]*<\/style>/i, '')
```

This completes immediately, but most of the regex examples I found online to match HTML tags were using the first way above, so I'm wondering what's the "right" way.

How would you do this?

Comment: Matching HTML with a regex is [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), is there a reason for not using an HTML Parser?

Comment: In addition to what AlexK. said, you might want to have a look at nokogiri http://www.nokogiri.org/

Comment: I use Nokogiri and Mechanize for HTML parsing. It turns out they don't properly handle `<style>` sections with no closing `</style>`. Without a closing `</style>`, it assumes the tag closes at the very end of the document.

Comment: I guess it's just invalid HTML, so classic HTML tools don't work properly.